# Start/Stop celery with Django

Tags: python, django, automation, celery

I have a django app that uses celery task and beat (periodic_task). I have written a script that start these two processes (Worker and beat) the way it should be.

I'm quite new to django and now I'm trying to figure out how I can start celery when my app also gets started, or in other words: **"How can I run the celery_start script at django app start"?**

Currently I have to trigger the celery_start script and the django app manually. And I would like to reduce this to a single app start.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: In development or in production?

Comment: prod. and dev. doesn't matter, i need an idea.

Comment: Yeah, that's just plain wrong, you have more flexibility in dev than you do in prod.  If in prod. use systemd or init.d scripts.  There are examples in the celery repo in github.

Comment: thanks for this hint